# Google Apps Script JSON.parse replaces all ":" (colon) in a URLFetchAPP with =" (equals sign)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, ide

JSON.parse of a URLFetchApp on Google App Scripts changes all colons in a string to an equals sign. It's doing the exact opposite of what I thought JSON.parse is supposed to do. I tried parsing the same string in different places and even made a node.js fetch and output all works. Seems to be a problem with Google AppScript

Example:

**CODE**

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
var text = res.getContentText()
var json = JSON.parse(text)
Logger.log(text)
Logger.log(json)
```

**LOG:**

```
{"status":{"timestamp":"2021-03-24T16:01:13.657Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":20,"credit_count":1,"notice":null},"data":[{"id":1,"symbol":"BTC","name":"Bitcoin","amount":1,"last_updated":"2021-03-24T16:00:03.000Z","quote":{"GBP":{"price":41091.43869808855,"last_updated":"2021-03-24T16:00:21.000Z"}}}]}

{status={elapsed=20.0, timestamp=2021-03-24T16:01:13.657Z, error_message=null, notice=null, credit_count=1.0, error_code=0.0}, data=[{amount=1.0, symbol=BTC, last_updated=2021-03-24T16:00:03.000Z, id=1.0, name=Bitcoin, quote={GBP={price=41091.43869808855, last_updated=2021-03-24T16:00:21.000Z}}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem, it's a feature.

Instead of `Logger.log(json)` use `Logger.log(JSON.stryngify(json))`.

Related

- [Log Javascript object as string Google App Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30895943/1595451)
- [Objects with and without quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56029092/1595451)